# how to create sliding menu for all Activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

Here Is Slide Menu Image That I want 
like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t51hnf1768xifsj/Screenshot_2014-07-02-13-47-32.png

Hello Guyes
i want to make Sliding Menu Like this Image .Top Of Sliding Menu Show User Logged Image .I m using Json
Sliding Should Work For All Activity .Guyes i m very New On Android .I dont How To make Sliding Menu Like This 
please Help Me To create Sliding Menu 
thanks In Advance

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: @Dhaval I m Trying To Learn From Android Hive ...when i start Activity In fragment Class through Intent ..After Opening Activity Slid Menu Is not Working

Comment: You'll need to maintain navigation drawer code in each activity if you use it your way

Comment: TO reduce the need for maintaining code for each activty, fragments are used.

Comment: @Dhaval can u please explain me How To Maintain ...Bcoz I m New So Please Answer..

Comment: Fragments aren't much different from activities, but they do have differences in terms of usage. Check out this example. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/ . This example used multiple fragments and shows how to replace them upon list item click. Learn fragments by searching for tutorials.

Comment: Please do not use links, include the actual image. And the text is scrambled and barely English. Please edit your question and correct.

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/sliding_menu_navigation_drawer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing `Navigation Drawer`.

Here is the example which will help you understand it better

[Navigation Drawer - android](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)  and [Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sir i m Trying To Learn Android Hive Sample Using Fragment ...When I start Activity In Fragment Through Intent ..Sliding Menu Is not Showing After Start Activity

Comment: As you see the example, you don't start a new activity for Navigation through different pages. You just add the transcation.

Comment: Sir Can U Explain Me ..where To Add Please ..I m new On Android ...Please Explain Me Acording To Android Hive exmple

Comment: Fing section **Handling Navigation Drawer List Item Click Event** on that same page.

Comment: i think .this 1 is used if (fragment != null) {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

   // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
   mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
   mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
   setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
   mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

Comment: Yes.Thats how you navigate through the fragments.